# How to show a menu at press/finger/mouse/cursor position in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have this piece of code which I got from [Style clipboard in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501448/style-clipboard-in-flutter)

```
showMenu(
        context: context,
        // TODO: Position dynamically based on cursor or textfield
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 600.0, 300.0, 0.0),
        items: [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                // TODO: Dynamic items / handle click
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    "Paste",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .body2
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text("Select All"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

This code works great, except that the popup that is created is at a fixed position, how would I make it so that it pops up at the mouse/press/finger/cursor position or somewhere near that, kind of like when you want to copy and paste on your phone. (This dialog popup will not be used for copy and pasting)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to solve a similar issue by using this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54714628/559525

Basically, I added a GestureDetector() around each ListTile and then you use onTapDown to store your press location and onLongPress to call your showMenu function.  Here are the critical functions I added:

```
  _showPopupMenu() async {
    final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

    await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
          _tapPosition & Size(40, 40), // smaller rect, the touch area
          Offset.zero & overlay.size // Bigger rect, the entire screen
          ),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Show Usage"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Delete"),
        ),
      ],
      elevation: 8.0,
    );
  }

  void _storePosition(TapDownDetails details) {
    _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
  }
}
```

And then here is the full code (you'll have to tweak a few things like the image, and filling in the list of devices):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class RecentsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RecentsPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _RecentsPageState createState() => _RecentsPageState();
}

class _RecentsPageState extends State<RecentsPage> {

  List<String> _recents;

  var _tapPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tapPosition = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    getRecents().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _recents = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(height: 25),
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                    child: Center(
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                        "Recents",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 0),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        child: Transform.scale(
                          scale: 2.0,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.chevron_left,
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  children: ListTile.divideTiles(
                    context: context,
                    tiles: _getRecentTiles(),
                  ).toList(),
                ),
              ),
              Container(height: 15),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _getRecentTiles() {
    List<Widget> devices = List<Widget>();
    String _dev;
    String _owner = "John Doe";

    if (_recents != null) {
      for (_dev in _recents.reversed) {
        if (_dev != null) {
          _dev = _dev.toUpperCase().trim();

            String serial = "12341234";

            devices.add(GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: _storePosition,
                onLongPress: () {
                  print("long press of $serial");
                  _showPopupMenu();
                },
                child: ListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  leading: Transform.scale(
                      scale: 0.8,
                      child: Image(
                        image: _myImage,
                      )),
                  title: AutoSizeText(
                    "$_owner",
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text("Serial #: $serial"),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                )));
        }
      }
    } else {
      devices.add(ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
        title: AutoSizeText(
          "No Recent Devices",
          maxLines: 1,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        subtitle:
            Text("Click the button to add a device"),
        onTap: () {
          print('add device');
        },
      ));
    }
    return devices;
  }

  _showPopupMenu() async {
    final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

    await showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
          _tapPosition & Size(40, 40), // smaller rect, the touch area
          Offset.zero & overlay.size // Bigger rect, the entire screen
          ),
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Show Usage"),
        ),
        PopupMenuItem(
          child: Text("Delete"),
        ),
      ],
      elevation: 8.0,
    );
  }

  void _storePosition(TapDownDetails details) {
    _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
  }
}
```

Comment: I got null error because _tapPosition  is not previously initialized even before the menu is shown. Just set it to _tapPosition  = Offset(0.0, 0.0); outside the build function then it won't give error and will update to new position when onTapDown is called.

Comment: Sorry, I never got that, but yea, you could write it to Offset(0.0, 0.0) inside initState() for a stateful widget like this for example.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: How to set _tapPosition = Offset(0.0, 0.0); I want to set menu position to top-right corner of screen according to different phone's screen sizes (width)? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Kamlesh first of all, setting _tapPosition to be 0,0 at the start of this stateful widget is to put that inside the initState() function.   I updated the answer above to include that one line.  But it sounds like you want something different, like always show pop up at the top right of any size screen?  In that case this other post may help you more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756271/how-to-set-flutter-showmenu-starting-point

Comment: offset: const Offset(0, -380), helped me. Thanks

Comment: Hi, in flutter 2 there seems to be a drift in this method. Do you find the cause?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Use gesture detector's onTapDown like this

```
 GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
          showPopUpMenu(details.globalPosition);
        },
```

then in this method we use tap down details to find position

```
Future<void> showPopUpMenu(Offset globalPosition) async {
double left = globalPosition.dx;
double top = globalPosition.dy;
await showMenu(
  color: Colors.white,
  //add your color
  context: context,
  position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, 0, 0),
  items: [
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: 1,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 40),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              "Menu 1",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: 2,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 40),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              "Menu 2",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      value: 3,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.power_settings_new_sharp),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            "Menu 3",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
  elevation: 8.0,
).then((value) {
  print(value);
  if (value == 1) {
    //do your task here for menu 1
  }
  if (value == 2) {
    //do your task here for menu 2
  }
  if (value == 3) {
    //do your task here for menu 3
  }
});
```

hope it works

Comment: Worked for me, just had to add context attribute on function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reusable widget which does what you need. Just wrap your `Text` or other `Widget` with this `CopyableWidget` and pass in the `onGetCopyTextRequested`. It will display the Copy menu when the widget is long pressed, copy the text contents returned to the clipboard, and display a `Snackbar` on completion.

```
/// The text to copy to the clipboard should be returned or null if nothing can be copied
typedef GetCopyTextCallback = String Function();

class CopyableWidget extends StatefulWidget {

    final Widget child;
    final GetCopyTextCallback onGetCopyTextRequested;

    const CopyableWidget({
        Key key,
        @required this.child,
        @required this.onGetCopyTextRequested,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _CopyableWidgetState createState() => _CopyableWidgetState();
}

class _CopyableWidgetState extends State<CopyableWidget> {

    Offset _longPressStartPos;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return InkWell(
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            onTapDown: _onTapDown,
            onLongPress: () => _onLongPress(context),
            child: widget.child
        );
    }

    void _onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
        setState(() {
            _longPressStartPos = details?.globalPosition;
        });
    }

    void _onLongPress(BuildContext context) async {
        if (_longPressStartPos == null)
            return;

        var isCopyPressed = await showCopyMenu(
            context: context,
            pressedPosition: _longPressStartPos
        );
        if (isCopyPressed == true && widget.onGetCopyTextRequested != null) {
            var copyText = widget.onGetCopyTextRequested();
            if (copyText != null) {
                await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: copyText));

                _showSuccessSnackbar(
                    context: context,
                    text: "Copied to the clipboard"
                );
            }
        }
    }

    void _showSuccessSnackbar({
        @required BuildContext context,
        @required String text
    }) {
        var scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
        if (scaffold != null) {
            scaffold.showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                    content: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                                Icons.check_circle_outline,
                                size: 24,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 8),
                            Expanded(
                                child: Text(text)
                            )
                        ],
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
}

Future<bool> showCopyMenu({
    BuildContext context,
    Offset pressedPosition
}) {
    var x = pressedPosition.dx;
    var y = pressedPosition.dy;

    return showMenu<bool>(
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(x, y, x + 1, y + 1),
        items: [
            PopupMenuItem<bool>(value: true, child: Text("Copy")),
        ]
    );
}
```