# Flutter - PopupMenu on long press

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making an image gallery and I need the user to be able to long-press an image to show a popup menu which will let him delete the image.

My code, so far:

```
  return GestureDetector(
    onLongPress: () {
      showMenu(
        items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: this._index,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.delete),
                Text("Delete"),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
        context: context,
      );
    },
    child: Image.memory(
      this._asset.thumbData.buffer.asUint8List(),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      gaplessPlayback: true,
    ),
  );
```

Which produces:
[image]

But also, I couldn't find out how to completely remove the image's widget when the longPress function is called. How to do so?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are going to use a gridView or listview for laying out the images on the screen, you can wrap each item with a gesture detector then you should keep your images in a list somewhere, then simply remove the image from the list and call setState().

Something like the following. (This code will probably won't compile but it should give you the idea)

```
    ListView.builder(
        itemCount: imageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: () {
                  showMenu(
                    onSelected: () => setState(() => imageList.remove(index))}
                    items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        value: this._index,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.delete),
                            Text("Delete"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                    context: context,
                  );
                },
                child: imageList[index],
            );
          }
       )
```

Edit: You can use a popup menu too, like following

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
  height: 100,
  width: 100,
  child: PopupMenuButton(
    child: FlutterLogo(),
    itemBuilder: (context) {
      return <PopupMenuItem>[new PopupMenuItem(child: Text('Delete'))];
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: I'm able to remove the image, but still unable to correctly position the menu, and when clicking Delete - the menu stays. How to solve?

Comment: I think using a PopupMenuButton may solve both of your problems. It takes a widget as a child so you can place your image inside it.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use a `PopupMenuButton` inside the `showMenu(...)`, as it's not an instance of `PopupMenuEntry`

Comment: You won't need to use showMenu if you can use popup menu button (Wrap your image in it). It will handle the displaying of the popup and as long as all your menu items have a value other than null it will close the popup too when an item is selected.

Comment: @avi12 Edited my answer to include an example of how you may use a popup menu button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187120/discussion-between-avi12-and-mertus).

Comment: After editing the 2nd code you suggested, I successfully made it

Answer (score 78):

The OP and the First Answerer bypassed the original problem using `PopupMenuButton`, which worked fine in their case. But I think the more general question of how to position one's own menu and how to receive the user's response *without using `PopupMenuButton`* is worth answering, because sometimes we want a popup menu on a custom widget, and we want it to appear on some gestures other than a simple tap (e.g. the OP's original intention was to long-press).

I set out to make a simple app demonstrating the following:

1. Use a `GestureDetector` to capture long-press
2. Use the function `showMenu()` to display a popup menu, and position it near the finger's touch
3. How to receive the user's selection
4. (Bonus) How to make a `PopupMenuEntry` that represents multiple values (the oft-used `PopupMenuItem` can only represent a single value)

The result is, when you long-press on a big yellow area, a popup menu appears on which you can select `+1` or `-1`, and the big number would increment or decrement accordingly:

[image: Popup Menu Usage App]

Skip to the end for the entire body of code. Comments are sprinkled in there to explain what I am doing. Here are a few things to note:

1. [`showMenu()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showMenu.html)'s `position` parameter takes some effort to understand. It's a [`RelativeRect`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RelativeRect-class.html), which represents how a smaller rect is positioned inside a bigger rect. In our case, the bigger rect is the entire screen, the smaller rect is the area of touch. Flutter positions the popup menu according to these rules (in plain English):

   - if the smaller rect leans toward the **left** half of the bigger rect, the popup menu would align with the **smaller rect's left edge**
   - if the smaller rect leans toward the **right** half of the bigger rect, the popup menu would align with the **smaller rect's right edge**
   - if the smaller rect is in the middle, which edge wins depends on the language's text direction. **Left edge** wins if using English and other left-to-right languages, right edge wins otherwise.

It's always useful to reference [`PopupMenuButton`'s official implementation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/237fc2fb45639312001e947bf7465ef9f23bb699/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart) to see how it uses `showMenu()` to display the menu.

2. `showMenu()` returns a `Future`. Use `Future.then()` to register a callback to handle user selection. Another option is to use `await`.
3. Remember that [`PopupMenuEntry`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/PopupMenuEntry-class.html) is a (subclass of) `StatefulWidget`. You can layout any number of sub-widgets inside it. This is how you represent multiple values in a `PopupMenuEntry`. If you want it to represent two values, just make it contain two buttons, however you want to lay them out.
4. To close the popup menu, use [`Navigator.pop()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html). Flutter treats popup menus like a smaller "page". When we display a popup menu, we are actually pushing a "page" to the navigator's stack. To close a popup menu, we pop it from the stack, thus completing the aforementioned `Future`.

Here is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Popup Menu Usage',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Popup Menu Usage'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _count = 0;
  var _tapPosition;

  void _showCustomMenu() {
    final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

    showMenu(
      context: context,
      items: <PopupMenuEntry<int>>[PlusMinusEntry()],
      position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
          _tapPosition & const Size(40, 40), // smaller rect, the touch area
          Offset.zero & overlay.size   // Bigger rect, the entire screen
      )
    )
    // This is how you handle user selection
    .then<void>((int delta) {
      // delta would be null if user taps on outside the popup menu
      // (causing it to close without making selection)
      if (delta == null) return;

      setState(() {
        _count = _count + delta;
      });
    });

    // Another option:
    //
    // final delta = await showMenu(...);
    //
    // Then process `delta` however you want.
    // Remember to make the surrounding function `async`, that is:
    //
    // void _showCustomMenu() async { ... }
  }

  void _storePosition(TapDownDetails details) {
    _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              // This does not give the tap position ...
              onLongPress: _showCustomMenu,

              // Have to remember it on tap-down.
              onTapDown: _storePosition,

              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                child: Text(
                  '$_count',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 100, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlusMinusEntry extends PopupMenuEntry<int> {
  @override
  double height = 100;
  // height doesn't matter, as long as we are not giving
  // initialValue to showMenu().

  @override
  bool represents(int n) => n == 1 || n == -1;

  @override
  PlusMinusEntryState createState() => PlusMinusEntryState();
}

class PlusMinusEntryState extends State<PlusMinusEntry> {
  void _plus1() {
    // This is how you close the popup menu and return user selection.
    Navigator.pop<int>(context, 1);
  }

  void _minus1() {
    Navigator.pop<int>(context, -1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: FlatButton(onPressed: _plus1, child: Text('+1'))),
        Expanded(child: FlatButton(onPressed: _minus1, child: Text('-1'))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. One minor update since this was originally posted. `overlay.size` is now `overlay.semanticBounds.size`

Comment: Thanks @Graham. But can you point me to the reference page of the property? I haven't kept up and couldn't find it.

Comment: Yeah go here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html. Then scroll down to the `semanticBounds` property. Then click on `Rect` right next to it, which take you to the `Rect` class. Then scroll down to the `size` property. From the docs it looks like `RenderBox` also has a `size` property, but I got a compilation error when I tried to use it with Flutter `v1.5.4`.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is really useful and the way the menu is implemented in Flutter was hard for me to understand in connection with ListView.builder.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't have the seems issue like avil12 however the magic ".then()" of your implement helped me. I needed how to detect the user selector after opening the popupmenu successfully.

Comment: Why the (40, 40) arguments for the size? This seems to move the menu 40dp to the left of the tap position. Why not (0, 0)?

Comment: ```'PlusMinusEntry.represents' ('bool Function(int)') isn't a valid override of 'PopupMenuEntry.represents' ('bool Function(int?)')```

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for ways to position the popup menu on longpress and this is the one that actually works for me.

Comment: This code is outdated there are many errors, may someone edit it please?

Answer (score 8):

Building on the answers by Nick Lee and hacker1024, but instead of turning the solution into a mixin, you could simply just turn it into a widget:

```
class PopupMenuContainer<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final List<PopupMenuEntry<T>> items;
  final void Function(T) onItemSelected;

  PopupMenuContainer({@required this.child, @required this.items, @required this.onItemSelected, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => PopupMenuContainerState<T>();
}


class PopupMenuContainerState<T> extends State<PopupMenuContainer<T>>{
  Offset _tapDownPosition;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details){
        _tapDownPosition = details.globalPosition;
      },
      onLongPress: () async {
        final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

        T value = await showMenu<T>(
          context: context,
          items: widget.items,

          position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
            _tapDownPosition.dx,
            _tapDownPosition.dy,
            overlay.size.width - _tapDownPosition.dx,
            overlay.size.height - _tapDownPosition.dy,
          ),
        );

        widget.onItemSelected(value);
      },
      child: widget.child
    );
  }
}
```

And then you'd use it like this:

```
child: PopupMenuContainer<String>(
  child: Image.asset('assets/image.png'),
  items: [
    PopupMenuItem(value: 'delete', child: Text('Delete'))
  ],
  onItemSelected: (value) async {
    if( value == 'delete' ){
      await showDialog(context: context, child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Delete image'),
        content: Text('Are you sure you want to delete the image?'),
        actions: [
          uiFlatButton(child: Text('NO'), onTap: (){ Navigator.of(context).pop(false); }),
          uiFlatButton(child: Text('YES'), onTap: (){ Navigator.of(context).pop(true); }),
        ],
      ));
    }
  },
),
```

Adjust the code to fit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

Nick Lee's answer can be turned into a mixin quite easily, which can then be used anywhere you want to use a popup menu.

The mixin:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide showMenu;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as material show showMenu;

/// A mixin to provide convenience methods to record a tap position and show a popup menu.
mixin CustomPopupMenu<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  Offset _tapPosition;

  /// Pass this method to an onTapDown parameter to record the tap position.
  void storePosition(TapDownDetails details) => _tapPosition = details.globalPosition;

  /// Use this method to show the menu.
  Future<T> showMenu<T>({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required List<PopupMenuEntry<T>> items,
    T initialValue,
    double elevation,
    String semanticLabel,
    ShapeBorder shape,
    Color color,
    bool captureInheritedThemes = true,
    bool useRootNavigator = false,
  }) {
    final RenderBox overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

    return material.showMenu<T>(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        _tapPosition.dx,
        _tapPosition.dy,
        overlay.size.width - _tapPosition.dx,
        overlay.size.height - _tapPosition.dy,
      ),
      items: items,
      initialValue: initialValue,
      elevation: elevation,
      semanticLabel: semanticLabel,
      shape: shape,
      color: color,
      captureInheritedThemes: captureInheritedThemes,
      useRootNavigator: useRootNavigator,
    );
  }
}
```

And then, to use it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './custom_context_menu.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Popup Menu Usage',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Popup Menu Usage'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with CustomPopupMenu {
  var _count = 0;

  void _showCustomMenu() {
    this.showMenu(
      context: context,
      items: <PopupMenuEntry<int>>[PlusMinusEntry()],
    )
    // This is how you handle user selection
    .then<void>((int delta) {
      // delta would be null if user taps on outside the popup menu
      // (causing it to close without making selection)
      if (delta == null) return;

      setState(() {
        _count = _count + delta;
      });
    });

    // Another option:
    //
    // final delta = await showMenu(...);
    //
    // Then process `delta` however you want.
    // Remember to make the surrounding function `async`, that is:
    //
    // void _showCustomMenu() async { ... }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              // This does not give the tap position ...
              onLongPress: _showCustomMenu,

              // Have to remember it on tap-down.
              onTapDown: storePosition,

              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                child: Text(
                  '$_count',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 100, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlusMinusEntry extends PopupMenuEntry<int> {
  @override
  double height = 100;

  // height doesn't matter, as long as we are not giving
  // initialValue to showMenu().

  @override
  bool represents(int n) => n == 1 || n == -1;

  @override
  PlusMinusEntryState createState() => PlusMinusEntryState();
}

class PlusMinusEntryState extends State<PlusMinusEntry> {
  void _plus1() {
    // This is how you close the popup menu and return user selection.
    Navigator.pop<int>(context, 1);
  }

  void _minus1() {
    Navigator.pop<int>(context, -1);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: FlatButton(onPressed: _plus1, child: Text('+1'))),
        Expanded(child: FlatButton(onPressed: _minus1, child: Text('-1'))),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer for 2023

In [Flutter 3.7](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-7-38cbea71133c) there is now a ContextMenuRegion widget that you can wrap around any existing widget. When the user long presses or right-clicks (depending on the platform), the menu you give it will appear.

```
 return Scaffold(                                        
   body: Center(                                         
     child: ContextMenuRegion(                           
       contextMenuBuilder: (context, offset) {           
         return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
           anchors: TextSelectionToolbarAnchors(         
             primaryAnchor: offset,                      
           ),                                             
           buttonItems: <ContextMenuButtonItem>[         
             ContextMenuButtonItem(                      
               onPressed: () {                           
                 ContextMenuController.removeAny();      
               },                                        
               label: 'Save',                            
             ),                                           
           ],                                             
         );                                               
       },                                                
       child: const SizedBox(                            
         width: 200.0,                                   
         height: 200.0,                                  
         child: FlutterLogo(),                           
       ),                                                 
     ),                                                   
   ),                                                     
 );
```

[image]

Comment: `ContextMenuRegion` doesn't seem to be a standard widget? The only reference I can find is some custom code in an examples directory: https://github.com/flutter/samples/blob/c47d327fe6b71716795f534c62d5abf3fa5fa44b/experimental/context_menus/lib/context_menu_region.dart#L10

Comment: Same. But I did find something similar here: https://pub.dev/packages/context_menus. Not sure but it works.