# showMenu position Flutter

Tags: flutter, position

i have a GridView Widget that contain some GridTiles that are wrapped with GestureDetector trying to showUp a menu to delete the GridTile when i have longPress on it ,,, everything is fine except that i want that menu to be shown from the point that i have clicked into not at the top of the app

```
    showMenu(
            context: context,
            position: ..........,// Here i want the solution
            items: [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _notesProv.deleteNote(id);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  label: Text(
                    'delete note',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            color: Colors.green[100],
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ));
```

Answer (score 10):

See comments in the code for guidance on what's going on.

Wherever there's a comment, that code was added to the example Gridview [stolen from Flutter official cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists) in order to pop up the menu where you tapped.

```
class GridPositionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GridPositionPageState createState() => _GridPositionPageState();
}

class _GridPositionPageState extends State<GridPositionPage> {

  // ↓ hold tap position, set during onTapDown, using getPosition() method
  Offset tapXY;
  // ↓ hold screen size, using first line in build() method
  RenderBox overlay;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ↓ save screen size
    overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject();

    return BaseExamplePage(
      title: 'Grid Position',
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(100, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                'Item $index',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
              ),
              // ↓ save screen tap position now
              onTapDown: getPosition,
              onLongPress: () => showMenu(
                  context: context,
                  position: relRectSize,
                  items: [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: FlatButton.icon(
                        label: Text('Delete'),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  // ↓ create the RelativeRect from size of screen and where you tapped
  RelativeRect get relRectSize => RelativeRect.fromSize(tapXY & const Size(40,40), overlay.size);

  // ↓ get the tap position Offset
  void getPosition(TapDownDetails detail) {
    tapXY = detail.globalPosition;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I hope this helps.

```
GestureDetector(
 onLongPressStart: (details) async{
  final offset = details.globalPosition;

  showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
      offset.dx,
      offset.dy,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - offset.dx,
      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - offset.dy,
    ),
    items: [
      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("0"),
      ),

      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("1"),
      ),

      PopupMenuItem(
        child: Text("2"),
      ),

    ]
);

},
 child: FaIcon(
   AppIcons.ellipseFa,
   size: 22,
 ),
)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This function handles everything, you just need to use the [findRenderObject](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element/findRenderObject.html) method to get the RenderObject on each grid item:

```
void showGridMenu() async {
      Rect? rect;
      RenderBox? overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      final renderObject = context.findRenderObject();
      final translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
      if (translation != null && renderObject?.paintBounds != null) {
      final offset = Offset(translation.x, translation.y);
      rect = renderObject!.paintBounds.shift(offset);
      }
      if (rect != null) {
      var value = await showMenu<String>(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromRect(
        rect,
        Offset.zero & overlay.size,
      ),
      items: [
        const PopupMenuItem(value: 'yes', child: Text('Yes')),
        const PopupMenuItem(value: 'no', child: Text('No')),
      ],
      );
      if (value != null) {
      debugPrint(value);
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: How to position from Bottom, when keyboard is opened?

Comment: Incredible answer. Handles proper offset with initialValue too, that's really hard to find online.

Answer (score -2):

```
position: RelativeRect.fromSize(
                        Rect.fromCenter(
                            center: Offset.zero, width: 100, height: 100),
                        Size(100, 100),
                  ),
```

Somthing like that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).