# How to set Flutter showMenu starting point

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to know how to change the origin point of the `popUpMenu`, start the popup right above the bottom app bar, no matter the count of items. Aligned to the right end of the screen. Something that is like (for example)

```dart
Positioned(right: 0, bottom: bottomAppBarHeight)
```

Here is a screenshot of the design placement of `popUpMenu` I want to achieve:

[image: Design]

Here is a screenshot of the current placement of the `popUpMenu` (Please ignore other design differences as they are irrelevant):

[image: Actual]

The code used is as follows :

```dart
                      onPressed: () {
                        final RelativeRect position =
                            buttonMenuPosition(context);
                        showMenu(context: context, position: position, items: [
                          PopupMenuItem<int>(
                            value: 0,
                            child: Text('Working a lot harder'),
                          ),
                          PopupMenuItem<int>(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Text('Working a lot less'),
                          ),
                          PopupMenuItem<int>(
                            value: 1,
                            child: Text('Working a lot smarter'),
                          ),
                        ]);
                      },
```

The `buttonMenuPosition` function code:

```dart
RelativeRect buttonMenuPosition(BuildContext context) {
    final bool isEnglish =
        LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate.currentLocale.languageCode == 'en';
    final RenderBox bar = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final RenderBox overlay =
        Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    const Offset offset = Offset.zero;
    final RelativeRect position = RelativeRect.fromRect(
      Rect.fromPoints(
        bar.localToGlobal(
            isEnglish
                ? bar.size.centerRight(offset)
                : bar.size.centerLeft(offset),
            ancestor: overlay),
        bar.localToGlobal(
            isEnglish
                ? bar.size.centerRight(offset)
                : bar.size.centerLeft(offset),
            ancestor: overlay),
      ),
      offset & overlay.size,
    );
    return position;
  }
```

Changing the offset didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain at which sequence you want to show pop up? other then what is shown on your UI.

Comment: I'd like to start the popup right above the bottom app bar, no matter the count of items.
Aligned to the right end of the screen.
Something that is like (for example) `Positioned(right: 0, bottom: bottomAppBarHeight)`

Comment: That will not work with pop up, you have to design custom widget for it

Comment: Can you please show me an example with code? in an answer of course not a comment.

Comment: so you want to open this on Tap of more option?

Comment: Yes, this `onPressed` function in the question is called when I tap the 'more option'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I couldn't achieve it with the `showMenu` function, but it was achievable by using a `PopUpMenuButton` and setting its offset to the height of the bottom app bar.

Here is an example code:

```dart
PopupMenuButton<int>(
    offset: const Offset(0, -380),
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
      PopupMenuItem<int>(
          value: 0,
          child: PopUpMenuTile(
            isActive: true,
            icon: Icons.fiber_manual_record,
            title:'Stop recording',
          )),
      PopupMenuItem<int>(
          value: 1,
          child: PopUpMenuTile(
            isActive: true,
            icon: Icons.pause,
            title: 'Pause recording',
          )),
      PopupMenuItem<int>(
          value: 2,
          child: PopUpMenuTile(
            icon: Icons.group,
            title: 'Members',
          )),
      PopupMenuItem<int>(
          value: 3,
          child: PopUpMenuTile(
            icon: Icons.person_add,
            title: 'Invite members',
          )),
    ],
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.more_vert,
            color: Colors.white60),
        Text(translate('more'),
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .caption)
      ],
    ),
  )
```

The code to the custom pop up menu tile is as follows even though it is not relevant to the question:

```dart
class PopUpMenuTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const PopUpMenuTile(
      {Key key,
      @required this.icon,
      @required this.title,
      this.isActive = false})
      : super(key: key);
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
  final bool isActive;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(icon,
            color: isActive
                ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 8,
        ),
        Text(
          title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(
              color: isActive
                  ? Theme.of(context).accentColor
                  : Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get similar behavior as follows:

```
    class _SettingsPopupMenuState extends State<SettingsPopupMenu> {
      static const Map<String, IconData> _options = {
       'Settings' : Icons.favorite_border,
       'Share'    : Icons.bookmark_border,
       'Logout'   : Icons.share,
      };

      void _showPopup(BuildContext context) async {
        //*get the render box from the context
        final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
        //*get the global position, from the widget local position
        final offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

        //*calculate the start point in this case, below the button
        final left = offset.dx;
        final top = offset.dy + renderBox.size.height;
        //*The right does not indicates the width
        final right = left + renderBox.size.width;

        //*show the menu
        final value = await showMenu<String>(
          // color: Colors.red,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
          ),
          context: context, 
          position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, 0.0), 
          items: _options.entries.map<PopupMenuEntry<String>>((entry) {
            return PopupMenuItem(
              value: entry.key,
              child: SizedBox(
                // width: 200, //*width of popup
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(entry.value, color: Colors.redAccent),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                    Text(entry.key)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()
        );

        print(value);
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Popup Settings'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              //*encloses the widget from which the relative positions will be 
              //*taken in a builder, in this case a button
              Builder(
                builder: (context) {
                  return RawMaterialButton(
                    fillColor: Colors.indigo,
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 200),
                    onPressed: () => _showPopup(context),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: const Text('Show Menu', style: TextStyle(color: 
    Colors.white)),
                  );
                }
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The one and only working code is here

```
Offset offs = Offset(0,0);
    final RenderBox button = context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    final RenderBox overlay = Navigator.of(context).overlay!.context.findRenderObject()! as RenderBox;
    final RelativeRect position = RelativeRect.fromRect(
      Rect.fromPoints(
        button.localToGlobal(offs, ancestor: overlay),
        button.localToGlobal(button.size.bottomRight(Offset.zero) + offs, ancestor: overlay),
      ),
      Offset.zero & overlay.size,
    );
```

This is taken from
[image]

Comment: Worked with setting initialValue!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but your code is one line from working and I couldn't see an answer that covered it.

You just need to change the following in the `buttonMenuPosition` function:

```
return position;
```

to

```
return position.shift(offset);
```